# Getting Castle AutoTx to work with Entity Framework (auto commit based on transaction attribute)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, castle-windsor, aop

I'm currently working on fitting Entity Framework into our in-house SDK. It currently features castle ioc, NHibernate. It needs to be able to work with both of them, hence a common IRepository interface, which has your basic functions such as FindById(object id); and Query(), as well as Save(T entity); If you're familiar with NHibernate, you know exactly what the last one does (calls SaveOrUpdate method). Basically I need it to mimic NHibernate's behaviour.

I need this Save(T entity); method to work as follows:
if it's a new object (can probably be distinguished via null ID, as we base all domain objects off of a single abstract entity), it adds it and saves. If it's modified, it just saves. All that could be taken care of with detecting the primary key (we use comb for ID generation). This is the harder part:

If any method in the stack has a Castle Transaction attribute, the first method that uses it, only once it reaches the end of that method, should it actually commit the changes.
This we achieve by using Castle AutoTx.

So if I have

```
public void Method1()
{
    _repository.Save(new Entity(){ Name = "1" );
    Method2();
}
[Transaction]
public void Method2()
{
    _repository.Save(new Entity(){ Name = "2" );
    _repository.Save(new Entity(){ Name = "2" );
    Method3();
}
[Transaction]
public void Method3()
{
    _repository.Save(new Entity(){ Name = "3" );
    _repository.Save(new Entity(){ Name = "3" );
}
```

Here: Entity with Name == "1" gets saved with its own transaction.
Entities with Name == "2" get saved together with Entities with Name == "3" in their transaction. The Transaction attribute on Method3 is ignored. Repository Save() method already has its own Transaction attribute.

Because Method2 had first Transaction attribute, all of the calls it does, are wrapped in the same transaction.

Quite frankly, I'm not sure how to do with with EF... something that is built into NHibernate...

**EDIT:**
The repository is not a generic one of Repository<MyEntity>, it's a Repository, with interface looking more like

```
public interface IRepository
{
    void Save<T>(T entity);
    IQueryable<T> Query<T>() where T : class;
    T FindById<T>(object id) where T : class;
}
```

etc

Comment: I don't think `[Transaction]` support is an NHibernate feature. It would need to be informed when the method with a `[Transaction]` attribute is invoked. That's AOP. Either achieved by proxying or by making a call to NHibernate telling it you want to execute `Save...` on some object. I've never seen NHibernate proxying anything but entitites. I rather think that it's a feature of your IoC (castle?) or you rolled your own..

Comment: I investigated it a little further, it seems it's simply Castle AutoTx facility. However, it doesn't seem to work with Entity Framework...